# How to use .js file with declarations .d.ts in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have Angular 7 app and I want to include some typed JS constants from outside of the project (These constants are used in the AngularJS app, so I need to keep it in js). I defined new path in paths in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"],
      "@dep/*": ["../../web-common/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

In @dep i have test.js and test.d.ts that contains following

```
export const TEST_CONST = {
  parser: 'CSV',
  styler: 'XVE'
};
```

and

```
export interface TEST_CONST {
  parser: string;
  styler: number;
}
```

But when I import it and start using

```
import {TEST_CONST} from '@dep/constants/test';
```

...

```
console.log(TEST_CONST.styler);
```

It gives me

> **error TS2693: 'TEST_CONST' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.**

I also tried to import '*@dep/constants/test.js*' but it is same....
How to import js file with typings into Angular app? As I understand it, this should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `declare` and remove `export`:

```
declare interface TEST_CONST {
  parser: string;
  styler: number;
}
```

Comment: It gives me File is not a module

Comment: and what if you import directly? `import {TEST_CONST} from '@dep/constants/test.js'`